# Enums with Associated Values in Python

Tags: python, enums, associated-value

In Swift Enums have something called an *Associated Value*. Consider the following:

```swift
enum Shape {
     case circle(radius: Double)
     case rectangle(x: Double, y: Double)
}
```

In this case the Enums' Associated Values are `radius` and `x` & `y` and can be individually set for each instantiation of that Enum. E.g. I could do

```swift
smallCircle = Shape.circle(radius: 12)
largeCircle = Shape.circle(radius: 36)
```

Is there something similar for the Python `Enum`? I tried around myself but without much success. It seems like whatever attribute I set will always be the same for all instantiations of that Enum - i.e. in above example the second line equivalent in Python would have set the radius to 36 on both `smallCircle` and `largeCircle`. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems more like a class/subclass relationship to me -- e.g. a base class `Shape` that's empty and then derived classes `Circle` and `Rectangle` with the appropriate attributes (possibly defined with `@dataclass`).  Does that have the semantics you'd be looking for?

Comment: Do you intend to make an unlimited number of circles, or just a few fixed types?

Comment: Its the former, i.e. a large number - that is the whole point and the nice thing about the way it is implemented in Swift. Was hoping to be able to re-create something similar in Python but seems like its not possible. Imagine the example above where you would also have nome cases with no attributes at all (in mz practical problem at hand thats the case).

Comment: enum members are meant to be singletons. You probably just don't want to use enums in Python, what is your use-case? There is something probably more appropriate with python

Answer (score 4):

In Python, the value associated with the symbolic names of Enums can be of *any type*. [Python Enum Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

Unlike Swift, from the Python documentation, the members of a Python Enum are **functionally constant**

So, the answer to your question is **no**.

Comment: yes, enum members are meant to be singletons.